# Using different versions of Crystal Reports on a same server

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a few web applications running on the same server. Recently I added crystal reports for VS 2010. I thought to use new reports for several of projects but not all. Other projects uses the older version of crystal reports

So I modified the web.config of the required projects. I downloaded runtime on both my development machine and server. So now I have both versions of asseblies (v 10 and v 13) in GAC. I have .NET 4.0 on both macines as well.

It has worked on development machine

However, when I run the same projects on server it raises an error.

CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll'

I am wondering why it works on my development machine and does not on server ? Do I have to configure something on server to make it happen ? Or do I need to add in someting in web.config file ?

If someknow knows it, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by commenting/deleting assembly references which refer to version 10.5.... in web.config. In addition I had to change manually correct version to register assembly="CrystalDecision.... in the .aspx file where I use Crystal report components.