# Is Possible to Run Multiple Versions of Crystal Reports Runtime on the Same Server?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to develop an ASP.NET Core application which uses the version of Crystal Reports that's on SP22. I will be deploying this application onto a Windows 2008 Server which already has another ASP.NET application which uses the version of Crystal Reports that's on SP17.

If I install the SP22 runtime on that server, will my existing application break or will they be able to run side by side without issues?

[This article](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1216278) talks about installing multiple versions of Crystal Reports for development purposes, but that's not that what I'm asking here. I'm talking about runtime only, not development.

[This question](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1295817) says we can install multiple Crystal Reports runtimes without issues, but it's too old and I'm wondering if things have changed since then. Especially since my existing application targerts .NET framework 2.0 and the new one will target .NET Framework 4.7.1

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256768/using-different-versions-of-crystal-reports-on-a-same-server), asked here about 4 years ago, still leaves me in the dark.

As I understand, the .NET CLR 2.0 is no longer supported by Crystal Reports (see [this document](https://www.sap.com/documents/2016/06/f871031e-757c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html), page 9). My existing application uses that runtime and I can not update it right now, thus I need to make sure that installing the new Crystal Reports runtime (the one on SP22) will not break that application.

Is it safe for me to install the latest Crystal Reports runtime on the Windows Server without fear of breaking my existing application?

Note: I asked this question in the [Crystal Reports community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/458592/multiple-versions-of-crystal-reports-runtime.html) last week and have gotten no response. I was hoping someone here would have some experience in the matter and would shed some light.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article from SAP supports you pointed out https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1216278
  applies not only for development purposes; it clearly explains which version can be installed on the same computer without issue :
Basically : each major can be installed on the same machine , but only one version of each major , since Crystal Reports 9.

So, if this is correct, you should not face any issue. I recommand nevertheless that you try before (test server, VM...)  modifying your production server